# This does not seem to be returning the correct object (Typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have created a small class, which wrappers around a generic callback function signature, and returns a promise.

however then it calls the **handle** menthod the **_resolve** is undefined.

```
/// <reference path="typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts" /> 
import rsvp = require('es6-promise'); 
var Promise = rsvp.Promise;

/**  * wrapper a callback style call into a promise  */ class
Promiseify<T> {
    private _promise : Promise<T>;
    private _resolve : (result?: T) => void;
    private _reject : (error: any) => void;

    /**
     * create wrapper, example: new Promiseify(call).promise
     * @param call example (handle) => yourDb.update(document, handle)
     */
    constructor(call:(handle:(error: any, result: T) => void) => void){

        this._promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) =>{
            this._resolve = resolve;
            this._reject = reject;
            call(this.handle);
        });

    }

    handle(error: any, result: T) {
        if(error != null) this._reject(error);
        else this._resolve(result);
    }

    /**
     * get the es6 promise which can then be passed to external callers
     * @returns {Promise<T>} the es6 promise which this class creates.
     */
    get promise() : Promise<T>{
        return this._promise;
    } 
}

//the test rig 
new Promiseify<string>((handle)=> {
    handle(null, 'hello world');
}).promise.then((greeting: string)=> {
        console.log(greeting);
    });
```

am i missing something, btw the JS under the covers looks ok too

also if it helps I am running this on Node.JS, inside Webstorm 9.03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `this.handle` into `call()`, so when `call()` calls it, `this` will be `null` and that is why your approach isn't working.

I'm not sure what would be most idiomatic in TypeScript, but you can do:

```
call(this.handle.bind(this));
```

or

```
call((error, result) => this.handle(error, result));
```

Alternatively, you could get rid of the `handle` method entirely, and do this:

```
this._promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
    call(function (error, result) {
        if (error) { reject(error); }
        resolve(result);
    });
});
```

but then that just leaves the question of why you need a class at all, when you could instead use an 8-line function that does the same thing:

```
function promisify<T>(call:(handle:(error: any, result :T) => void) => void) {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        call(function (error, result) {
            if (error) { reject(error); }
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: used the latter, which works. shame this small wrapper is needed.

Comment: @dbones It's only needed if you keep the initial design you had. Please see my edits.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

The first one is to declare the handle method as a property like so:

```
handle = (error: any, result: T) => {
    if(error != null) this._reject(error);
    else this._resolve(result);
}
```

Or change your call method so it calls it on the instance like below:

```
var that = this;
call(function(e, r) { that.handle(e, r); });
```